# How can I use pure javascript to append form's action as hidden element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bookmarklet

I'm trying to write a bookmarklet to change the action of all forms on a page to a specified URL, for this example I'm using google.com, and also to add a hidden form element named "action" with the original value.

I've got the first part working:

```
javascript:(function(){var x,i; x = document.forms; for (i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) x[i].action="http://www.google.com/"; })();
```

But how do I use pure javascript to append the forms' original action as a **new** hidden element, like this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="http://original-action-url.com" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, This ->

```
var action = document.forms[0].action;
document.getElementsByName('action')[0].setAttribute("value", action);
```

Edit (after your comment) -->

```
y = document.forms; 
for (i = 0; i < y.length; ++i){
var x = document.createElement("input");
x.setAttribute("name", "hiddenAction" + i);
x.setAttribute("type","hidden");
x.setAttribute("value",y[i].getAttribute("action"));
y[i].appendChild(x); //you said Appended to the form.
}
```

Havent tested it, so might require a bit of tweaking.
Hope that helps.

Comment: almost. the hidden element does not yet exist, it will have to be created with javascript and appended to the form. also it would be great if it could loop through all forms on the page and do it.

Comment: changed `y.appendChild(x)` to `y[i].appendChild(x)` and then it worked very well. thank you!